# How to write nested DTOs in NestJS

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, dto

I am a beginner in NestJS and I want to write a DTO for below structure -

```
{
    something: {
        info: {
            title: string,
            score: number,
            description: string,
            time: string,
            DateOfCreation: string
        },
        Store: {
            item: {
                question: string,
                options: {
                    item: {
                        answer: string,
                        description: string,
                        id: string,
                        key: string,
                        option: string
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to write a DTO for that nested Data object. I can't find a solid example for writing nested DTO in NestJS. I am a beginner in NestJS and I have never worked with DTO before. So please don't assume that I know something. I am using it with Mongoose.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You will have to create separate classes for each object in your schema and a main class which will import all the classes.

```
import { Type } from "class-transformer";

class Info {
    readonly title:string
    readonly score:number
    readonly description:string
    readonly dateOfCreation:Date
}

export class SampleDto {
    @Type(() => Info)
    @ValidateNested()
    readonly info: Info

    ...Follow same for the rest of the schema

}
```

Refer: https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#validating-nested-objects

Comment: Ooh my god this thing was staring right at my face but I couldn't see it. Thank you very much. Marking this as accepted answer. And here's another answer for same question for future readers - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53786383/validate-nested-objects-using-class-validator-and-nestjs

Comment: Note that it's @ValidateNested(), not @ValidatedNested()

Comment: From where to import @Type. I can not find it in class-validator

Comment: import { Type } from "class-transformer";

Answer (score -4):

//example :

```
export class UserBaseDto {
  @ApiProperty({
    type: String,
    required: true,
    description: 'email user, minlength(4), maxlength(40)',
    default: "test@email.com",
  })
  @IsString()
  @MinLength(4)
  @MaxLength(40)
  @IsNotEmpty() 
  email: string;
//....enter code here
}
```