# NestJS class-validators on incoming requests using interface

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, class-validator

I need to use an interface through class-validator to validate the incoming form for a specific field in the incoming request body.

The interface:

```js
export enum Fields {
  Full_Stack_Dev = 'full stack dev',
  Frontend_Dev = 'frontend dev',
  Backend_Dev = 'backend dev',
}

export interface Experience {
  field: Fields;
  years: number;
}
```

And here is the `DTO` Class:

```js
@IsEnum(Languages)
  languages: Languages[];

  experience: Experience[]; //  Not sure which decorator to use for interfaces
```

Comment: you can use interfaces in there but you'll need to pass some concrete class to `class-validator`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53786899/5290447

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay after doing a lot of research, I found a workaound for this:

**First of all, Interfaces CANNOT be used directly**. Officially declared by class-validators issue [here](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator/issues/159)

This is what I did:

1. Changed the interface into a **separate class** and added validation on its properties

```
class ExperienceDto {
  @IsEnum(Fields)
  field: Fields;
  @IsNumber()
  years: number;
}
```

2. Then used this class as type to validate **Array of Objects in the ACTUAL DTO CLASS (not the above one)**

```
  @ArrayNotEmpty()
  @ArrayMinSize(1)
  @ArrayMaxSize(3)
  @ValidateNested({ each: true })
  @Type(() => ExperienceDto) // imported from class-transformer package
  experience: ExperienceDto[];
```