# I'm trying to validate nested objects using class-validator and NestJS. Nested object id can not validate

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

I have tried some codes but i can not validate organization id , role id . Both are nested like fields. In the postman request both ids are inside object. how we can use DTO class for validate those fields. Below I have attached my postman request body and DTO class also.

**This is my postman request**

```
{
  "firstName":"abxc",
  "lastName": "absh",
  "login": "user_{{$randomEmail}}",
  "password":"test123",
  "organization": {
      "id":1
  },
  "role":{
      "id":1
  }
}
```

**CreateUserDTO class**

```
export class CreateOrganizationDTO {
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsNumber()
  id: number;
}
export class CreateUserDto {
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsString()
  firstName: string;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsString()
  lastName: string;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsEmail()
  login: string;

 
  organization: {
    id: number;
  };

  role: {
    id: number;
  };
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Validate nested objects using class validator and nestjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53786383/validate-nested-objects-using-class-validator-and-nestjs)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.