# create nested dto in typeorm

Tags: javascript, nestjs, typeorm

I've a dto called updateUserDTO and the class looks like this

```
@IsString()
full_name: string;

@IsNumber()
mobile: string;

@IsEmail()
email: string;

@IsOptional()
location: string;

@IsOptional()
landmark: string;

@IsOptional()
city: string;
```

How can I create a nested DTO, so when my response I post to my controller looks like this

```
{
    "full_name": "xyz",
    "mobile": 1231341451,
    "email": "xyz@abc.com",
    "address": {
         "location": "new avenue",
         "landmark": "Opp to St louis",
         "city": "Buffalo"  
    }
}
```

Comment: You can return Object from address field I guess. like address: Address. I found information the data a bit old but maybe it can work: https://aedart.github.io/athenaeum/archive/current/dto/nested-dto.html#example

Comment: @gguney, I just found an answer here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53786383/validate-nested-objects-using-class-validator-and-nestjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53786383/validate-nested-objects-using-class-validator-and-nestjs)

Answer (score 0):

you can use automapper to do that check the doc here :
https://automapperts.netlify.app/docs/nestjs

Answer (score 0):

Just **class-transformer** for nested validation.

1. *Divide you JSON into Parts*
2. *Do the use of **class-transformer** to validate a nested object*

**For Example**

```
import { Type } from 'class-transformer';
import { IsDefined, IsNotEmptyObject, IsOptional, IsString, 
ValidateNested } from 'class-validator';
// ################# Second Level Class #################

export class SecondLevel {
  @IsOptional()
  location: string;

  @IsOptional()
  landmark: string;

  @IsOptional()
  city: string;
}

// ############## First Level Class ###############

export class firstLevel {
  @IsString()
  full_name: string;

  @IsNumber()
  mobile: string;

  @IsEmail()
  email: string;

  @IsDefined()
  @IsNotEmptyObject()
  @ValidateNested()
  @Type(() => SecondLevel)
  address: SecondLevel;
}
```