# How to add nested dto in nestjs?

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-swagger

I'm trying to create a DTO that has another DTO as array, but when sending the body, nestjs/swagger not detecting the body content.
My DTOs are:

```
export class CreatePageDto {
  @ApiHideProperty()
  createAt: Date;

  @ApiHideProperty()
  updateAt: Date;

  @ApiProperty({
    type: CreatePageTranslateDto,
    isArray: true,
  })
  translations: CreatePageTranslateDto[];
}


export class CreatePageTranslateDto {
  @ApiProperty()
  slug: string;

  @ApiProperty()
  title: string;

  @ApiProperty({
    enum: AvailableLanguages,
  })
  lang: AvailableLanguages;
}
```

When a post a body like this:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:3000/pages' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
  "translations": [
    {
      "slug": "nombre-de-ejemplo",
      "title": "Nombre de ejemplo",
      "lang": "es"
    }
  ]
}'
```

I get an empty body.

Comment: Do you have the `ValidationPipe` in use? And if so, do you have `whitelist: true`?

Comment: Yes Jay, that was the problem. When I removed Validation Pipe, it worked. I will check the right way. Thank you.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53786899/7119067) seems to cover it very well.

Answer (score 1):

you have to do this below to validate nested DTO

```
 import { Type } from 'class-transformer';
 import { ValidateNested } from 'class-validator';

  @ApiProperty({
    type: CreatePageTranslateDto,
    isArray: true,
  })  
  @ValidateNested({ each: true })
  @Type(() => CreatePageTranslateDto)
  translations: CreatePageTranslateDto[];
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was class-validator. I decided to set class validator globally and I didn't do it right. The problem was due to the whitelist property set to true: *"if set to true validator will strip validated object of any properties that do not have any decorators"*.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You have to switch the class position first and then please add this decorator `@ApiExtraModels()` above the class `CreatePageTranslateDto`.

So, the code will be like this:

```
@ApiExtraModels() <-----
export class CreatePageTranslateDto {
  @ApiProperty()
  slug: string;

  @ApiProperty()
  title: string;

  @ApiProperty({
    enum: AvailableLanguages,
  })
  lang: AvailableLanguages;
}

export class CreatePageDto {
  @ApiHideProperty()
  createAt: Date;

  @ApiHideProperty()
  updateAt: Date;

  @ApiProperty({
    type: CreatePageTranslateDto,
    isArray: true,
  })
  translations: CreatePageTranslateDto[];
}
```