# Why does whitelist dont get error with wrong model NestJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, nestjs

I want to use a white list in my route's body validation. I expect that only data is accepted that confirms to my model and if some parameter is sent that is not part of my model DTO an error must be thrown.

**This is my DTO :**

```
export class RegisterDTO {
    @MinLength(5)
    userName: string;

    @MinLength(8)
    password: string;

    @IsNotEmpty()
    seller: boolean;

    address: {
        city: string;
        street: string;
        apartment?: string;
    };
}
```

**This is my controller :**

```
@Post('register')
@UsePipes(new ValidationPipe({ transform: true, whitelist: true}))
async register(@Body() userDTO: RegisterDTO) {
    const user = await this.userService.create(userDTO);
    const payload: Payload = {
        userName: user.userName,
        seller: user.seller,
    };

    const token = await this.authService.signPayload(payload);
    return {user, token};
}
```

**But when I sent this data I dont get an error:**

```
{
   "userName": "userdasdnasdasdadad",
   "password": "passwdasdasdasadasdasda",
   "address": {
      "city": "kiev",
      "street": "amosova"
   },
   "seller": false,
   "test": "test"
}
```

**"test": "test" must be not allowed as a parameter; I expect an error to be thrown but there is none**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The option `whitelist` only strips unknown values when the json is transformed into your dto class *without* throwing an error, so in your case the property `test` is silently removed.

If you want to throw a validation error when an unknown property is encountered, you need to add the option `forbidNonWhitelisted`:

```
@UsePipes(
    new ValidationPipe({
      transform: true,
      whitelist: true,
      forbidNonWhitelisted: true,
    }),
  )
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I have added forbidNonWhitelisted: true;
It remove test from responce, but doesnt throw an error
https://snag.gy/ideuRb.jpg

Comment: It is work as all fine and give me token , but i sent wrong model and wanna to get an error

Comment: Mh, that's weird. I've tried it here and it works: https://codesandbox.io/s/9jlkpxv744?fontsize=14&module=%2Fsrc%2Fapp.controller.ts

Comment: When you sent a POST request to https://9jlkpxv744.sse.codesandbox.io/ with `{
 "username": "kiwi",
 "firstname": "123456"
}` you'll get a 400 with `"whitelistValidation": "property firstname should not exist"`

Comment: Thanks. It help me. Problem was that i define to use globalPipe adn add forbidNonWhitelisted only local to controler but forgot to add to globaluse

Comment: It is happen because my globalUsePipe dont work(( and i add ValidationPipe to controler

Comment: But also I saw. That props without  _@Decorator from validation class also dont allowed and you must use _@Allow

Comment: Yup, that's true! Please also see this answer, if you want to use nested validation (for example for your address): https://stackoverflow.com/a/53685045/4694994