# How to implement conditional Validation in Nested DTOs - NestJS?

Tags: validation, nestjs, dto, class-validator

I am working in NestJS Project, there is one situation where I need to implement conditional Validation.

So my Payload looks like this:

```
{
  user_id: "123"
  user_type: "M" //Value Can be M or F
  inner_details: {
     name: {
             firstname:"akshay",
             lastname:"nikte"
           },
     email: "ak@test.com"
  },
  user_co: "Tesla"
}
```

So in above payload(body) there are some validation requirement as below:

If user_type = M then Firstname and Lastname both cannot be Empty

If user_type = F then Firstname cannnot be Empty but Lastname can be Empty

For this I created 3 DTO classes:

```
  Filename: create-user.dto.ts  
  export Class CreateUserDTO {
    
    @IsNotEmpty()
    @ApiProperty({
    required:true
    })
    user_id: string
    
    @IsNotEmpty()
    @ApiProperty({
    required:true
    })
    user_type: string
    
    @ValidateNested({each:true})
    @Type(()=>InnerDetailsDTO)
    inner_details: InnerDetailsDTO
    
    @IsNotEmpty()
    user_co: string
    
    }
    
    filname: inner-details.dto.ts
    export class InnerDetailsDTO {
    
     @ValidateNested({each: true})
     @Type: NameDTO
     name: NameDTO

     @IsNotEmpty
     @ApiProperty({
     required: true
     })
     email: string
    }

    filename name.dto.ts
    export class NameDTO {
    
       @IsNotEmpty()
       @ApiProperty({required: true})
       firstname: string

       @Validateif(check if UserType==="M") // How to access UserType from CreateUser DTO
       @IsNotEmprty()
       lastname: string  
    }
```

I have have 3 different DTOs in 3 different Files, how to use attribute from 1 DTO in another DTO ?

In my NameDTO I want apply conditional validation, when user_type==M then validate both Firstname and Lastname but when user_type==F Then only validate Firstname and not Lastname

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53650528/validate-nested-objects-using-class-validator-in-nest-js-controller

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [yup](https://github.com/jquense/yup). There you can also make conditional validation. But therefore you have to setup yup as a Validation Pipeline in Nestjs as well. See this npm module [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nestjs-yup-validator). But this package is not really popular, so I would implement it myself (I actually did that and it works pretty well). This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cmZcZb0qxqg) explains it really good.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but there is nothing wrong in having Multiple DTOs and Validation in that DTOs

Comment: I edited my answer since you really want to the validation in the DTO